# Constraints in other schema

Tags: postgresql, constraints, information-schema

When experimenting with the `information_schema.*` views, I learned that constraints can be defined in another schema. This is reflected in the `information_schema.table_constraints` view, which adds column such as `constaint_schema` to denote this:

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints

constraint_catalog | constraint_schema | constraint_name | table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | constraint_type | is_deferrable | initially_deferred
```

For foreign keys, this makes sense: it is possible to refer to a table in another schema.

I am now wondering if this is also applicable for other constraints. That is, is it somehow possible that a primary, unique or check constraint is defined in another schema as the schema in which the table is defined?
In which cases will `constraint_schema` be different than `table_schema` in `information_schema.table_constraints`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html

> the index is always created in the same schema as its parent table

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree
>   index on the column or group of columns listed in the constraint.

and

> Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique B-tree index
>   on the column or group of columns listed in the primary key

Thus pk or unique will surely travel with table in same schema. Regarding check and not null - I can't think of any way to argue why they can't be in different schema, but either I don't see any reason how they could appear in different schema...